# How to upload an iPhone app with(paid) "$1" cost in Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a question about submitting my app in Apple App Store with **"paid ($1 or $2 cost)"**. Previously I submitted many apps in app store but those are free, not paid.

[image]

In the above screen shot there was an option like: **"Price Tier"**. What does **Tier** mean?

Now I am going to publish a new app to App Store and it should be paid. How can I do this?

Comment: The tier defines the price. Click on the "View Pricing Matrix" link to the prices for each tier.

Answer (score 1):

Prices are different in each App Store territory. For example, the cheapest paid app in the USA may be $0.99 but in Canada, the price may be $1.29 due to differing exchange rates.

To set your app's price, you must choose a tier (which is typically in increments of US dollars) to account for differing currencies and their exchange rates. For the lowest priced paid app, you must choose the first paid tier.

Comment: ThanQ..@Aaron Wojnowski,  For know i am trying to add USA ($0.99)